# Esconder caminho das pastas com .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Olar. Estou trabalhando com um arquivo .htaccess mas estou com uma grande dificuldade em realizar o que eu preciso.

Tenho o domínio **site.com.br/painel/view/painel_de_acesso.php** e gostaria de converter essa url em **site.com.br/painel_de_acesso**

Qual lógica eu poderia inserir no meu .htaccess para conseguir este feito neste arquivo e todos os outros arquivos que estão dentro da pasta painel/view/?

Answer (score 1):

Crie na pasta raiz um arquivo com o nome `.htaccess` e adicione isto:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)$ painel/view/$1.php [L]
```

Se os arquivos tiverem letras maiusculas e minusculas pode ajustar assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)$ painel/view/$1.php [NC,L]
```

- O `([a-z0-9_]+)` procure somente arquivos com nome que tenha letras, números e underline
- O `^` e o `$` fazem verificar do começo ao fim para fazer o "match"
- O `$1` pega o que tiver dentro do parantes e adiciona para obter a requisição "verdadeira"
- O `NC` faz a regex ser case-insenstive (no primeiro não tem)
- O `L` faz ignorar as próximas regras (`RewriteRule`) evitando conflitos

Se ocorrer *erro 500* pode ser duas possibilidades:

- Você adicionou algo a mais dentro do teu .htaccess, que esta conflitando
- Ou você não habilitou o mod_rewrite no apache (o que é meio raro hoje em dia de ocorrer)